# pandas' `merge` drops levels on multiindex joins

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I don't understand why `merge` call below dropped the zero level `l0` while `join` didn't? I don't see that behavior described in the docs. Any explanation?

```
import string
import pandas as pd
alph = string.ascii_lowercase

n=5
inds = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(i,j) for i in alph[:n] for j in range(1,n)])
t = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0,10, len(inds)), index=inds).sort_index()
t.index.names=['l0', 'l1']

t2 = pd.DataFrame(data = [222,333], index=[2,3])
t2.index.names = ['l1']
display(t, t2)
display(t.merge(t2,how='left', on='l1'))
display(t.join(t2,how='left', on='l1', lsuffix='_x', rsuffix='_y'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) in your `merge` call and give it the `index` of `t` to preserve your `l0` index:

```
t.merge(t2,how='left', on='l1').set_index(t.index)
```

Printing the above when I ran the code gave me the following:

```
       0_x    0_y
l0 l1            
a  1     5    NaN
   2     7  222.0
   3     3  333.0
   4     5    NaN
b  1     4    NaN
   2     2  222.0
   3     0  333.0
   4     8    NaN
c  1     8    NaN
   2     2  222.0
   3     9  333.0
   4     9    NaN
d  1     3    NaN
   2     4  222.0
   3     2  333.0
   4     1    NaN
e  1     7    NaN
   2     1  222.0
   3     2  333.0
   4     0    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, I get this. but why would the merge has this oddity? It's non-sensical.

Comment: It is because of the differences between `join()` and `merge()`.  `join()` is used to combine two DataFrames on the `index` but **not on** `columns` whereas `merge()` is primarily used to specify the `columns` you wanted to join on, this also supports joining on indexes and combination of index and columns. See the [`documentation`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) for more info.